# Placing a word in its sorted location : Truly pythonic approach

Tags: python, sorting, lambda

I am editing this query, please accept my apologies if anyone feels that I have 
misled them into solving a different problem. I have got a file that contains the 
names of planets, something like this:

```
Neptune
Venus
Pluto
Uranus
Jupiter
Saturn
Mars
Earth
Mercury
Majikthise
```

Notice that one of them is not a planet(for now, lets assume that Pluto is a planet), I have a list of named planets and that looks like this:

```
planets = ['Neptune', 'Venus', 'Pluto', 'Uranus', 'Jupiter', 'Saturn',
           'Mars', 'Earth', 'Mercury']
```

Now, I am trying to check if the file contains any non-planet words and when I find one I move it to its proper place in the planet list such as it would be if the list were sorted. So the output if I were to print the list should look something like so:

```
['Neptune', 'Venus', 'Majikthise', 'Pluto', 'Uranus', 'Jupiter', 'Saturn',
 'Mars', 'Earth', 'Mercury']
```

Notice that in the above output 'Majikthise' is in exactly the place it would be
 in this list **if** this list was sorted. I was earlier under the impression that 
I was able to do that, but I was **not** able to do that, I thought I could do it
 due to a peculiarity in the inputs I used to test the code i.e. I used 
'Abracadabra' whose natural position in this list would be at the beginning(if 
sorted) and thats where I found it, but what I was doing was just appending the 
planets list to the non-planet, now though I am able to do what I was looking to 
do, only I am not sure if I achieved this in the most economical way. This is what 
I am doing:

```
with open("./names.txt","r") as names:
    names = list(map(lambda x: x.rstrip(),names)
    planets.insert(sorted(names).index
            (list(filter(lambda x: x not in planets, names))[0],
                    list(filter(lambda x: x not in planets, names))[0])
    print(planets)
```

My problem seems to have changed from the last time, I am now basically creating 
two lists, sorting one to find the sorted position of the non planet and **then** 
inserting the non planet in the unsorted planets list at the index it would find 
itself in if the planets list was sorted.

Can I now do something in place instead of creating 2 lists, does python provide 
anything in the builtins that can do this?

Comment: I don't understand the thing about ordering. The planets are not sorted, so where is the "correct" place for the word? What would the output look like if the word was "Majikthise"?

Comment: "it's proper place if the list were sorted lexicographically" -- I'm having a hard time picturing this since the list isn't sorted lexicographically (the planets are in a different order).  What happens if `Plato` is in the list?  Does it go before `Pluto`, or with the other P's?  To phrase the question differently, where do the planets to with respect to the lexicographically sorted elements?

Comment: Also, Is Pluto a planet?  :-P

Comment: If you have a non planet word "Magic" where should it go? Before Neptune? Before Mars? Or, before Mercury?

Comment: I agree with your reasoning about why you can't use `names` in your complicated `print` line. But what happens if you delete `names2` and use `names1` in its place instead? I don't think you need two names here, especially since they are references to the same list object.

Comment: @Daniel ['Neptune', 'Venus', 'Majikthise', 'Pluto', 'Uranus', 'Jupiter', 'Saturn', 'Mars', 'Earth', 'Mercury']

Comment: @mgilson My apologise with respect to Pluto. :P

Comment: @karafka I guess my response to Daniel answers your query.

Comment: @Kevin I think I have finally figured out a way to not use more than one list.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to sort the non-planet list but not the planet list. If that's the case, you could easily split into two lists, then sort the non-planet lists and merge it with planet lists.

```
planet_lists = [...]

with open('./names.text', 'r') as name_file:
     names = map(lambda name: name.strip(), name_file.readlines())
     non_planet_lists = filter(lambda name: name not in planet_lists, names)

result_list = sorted(non_planet_lists) + planet_lists
```

Comment: Actually no, thats not what I am looking for, I am able to achieve that, I need to work my query better, I am doing that, hopefully that will make it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

with list comprehensions

```
np=sorted([e for e in words if e not in planets]) 
p=[e for e in words if e in planets]
np+p
```

separate nonplanets from the planets from the given words list; sort nonplanets and join with planets given in the words list.  words may not include all planets so p is required as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your are correct when you say you have to *seek()* back to the start of the stream to use names again. @Kevin is also right when he says *names1* and *names2* are the same object, which you can check be doing a simple equality comparison. In any case you don't need either of them, by doing the following:

```
 with open("./names.txt", "r") as names:
        print(sorted(filter(lambda y: y not in planets, map(lambda x: x.rstrip(), names))) + planets)
```

hope that this helps

Comment: I will be editing my query for better understanding, I am looking for something slightly different.